# DocumentHeaderTemplate affects title set on LayoutAnchorables

Tags: wpf, xaml, avalondock

I have implemented the solution given in [AvalonDock2 : LayoutItemTemplate only for documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668705/avalondock2-layoutitemtemplate-only-for-documents). However I have a problem with setting the title on my Documents. I have inserted a DocumentHeaderTemplate

```
        <xcad:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content.Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </xcad:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>
```

This works for my bounded documents, but overrides my Title set on my LayoutAnchorable and gives an empty title when I set this. If I remove the DocumentHeaderTemplate I get my desired title on the anchorables, but not on my documents. My LayoutAnchorable follows:

```
                 <xcad:LayoutAnchorable ContentId="Log" Title="Log" CanClose="False">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing more I found out the answer myself and post it here if someone got the same question.

`DocumentHeaderTemplate` affects items that is placed on `LayoutDocumentPane`, it is not related to the Layout of the item. So if you place a `LayoutAnchorable` on a `LayoutDocumentPane` it will be affected by the `DocumentHeaderTemplate`.